# How does this C code return an enum?

Tags: c, enums

I am a bit confused about the following `if_even` function. How is the return type FLAGS? This seems strange - isn't an enum just a list of multiple integers to be used like `#define`'s ?

```
enum flag_o_e {EVEN, ODD};
enum flag_o_e test1;
typedef enum flag_o_e FLAGS;

FLAGS if_even(int n);

main()
{
  int x;
  FLAGS test2; 

  printf("input an integer: ");  scanf("%d", &x);
  test2 =  if_even(x); 
  if (test2 == EVEN)
    printf("test succeeded (%d is even)\n", x);
  else
    printf("test failed (%d is odd)\n", x);system("pause");
}

FLAGS if_even(int  n)
{
  if (n%2)
    return ODD;
  else
    return EVEN;

   }
```

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the enum declared at declared at the very top `enum flag_o_e {EVEN, ODD};` is just the same as doing

```
#define EVEN 0
#define ODD 1
typedef int flag_o_e;
```

Then there is a further typedef to use FLAGS in place of flag_o_e so its essentially:

```
#define EVEN 0
#define ODD 1
typedef int FLAGS;
```

So when if_even() executes `return EVEN;` its actually returning an int, and similarly the comparison of the result `if (test2 == EVEN)` is comparing the result (which is really an int) with EVEN, which is also an int.

typedef's can get a little confusing, but its just a technique to rename a type (such as int, or 'struct foo')  to something more readable and contextual.

Comment: Though as noted by other answers, enum is a distinct type, not simply an alias for a bunch of #define FOO n, so maybe my answer is just more confusing ;D

Answer (score 3):

Actually, an enum is a new type. It is not just some alias for int. (It can be converted to and from int, though.)

Answer (score 2):

`ODD` and `EVEN` are members of the enum `flag_o_e` which was typedeffed so that it can be called `FLAGS`. So returning either from a function returns a member of that enum (enums can be thought of as restricted integer types with names).

I think your issue is that you weren't aware that defining an enum is essentially defining a new type that can be used as input or output for functions.

Answer (score 1):

Enums in C have an explicit definition. The underlying values of the enum maps to integers, and can be used interchangeably with ints. You can declare enums and typedef enums as you would with structs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages

Answer (score 1):

the return type FLAGS ties in with the enumeration data type. Right now the enum shows EVEN = 1 and ODD = 2. These are bit flags. Using an 'int' return type works just as well for this program. Using FLAGS would be more if you wanted to use a different type of enumeration, like hex, oct, etc. A good way to think about enumerations is an ordered value, and being able to tie that into a word. These work well with maps, ints...basically anything that needs to be somehow tied to a number.